# UITextView beginningOfDocument returns nil

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I have to get the position on the screen of a string contained in a `UITextView`. To do that, I tried to get the corresponding UITextPosition(s). The problem is that the `UITextView` method `beginningOfDocument` returns `nil` (same for `endOfDocuement`). Could someone explain me why? And which solution I could use.

My code looks like this:

```
- (UITextRange *)getRangeOfString:(NSString *)string inTextView:(UITextView *)tv
{
    UITextPosition *beginning = [tv positionFromPosition:tv.beginningOfDocument offset:[tv.text rangeOfString:string].location];
    UITextPosition *end = [tv positionFromPosition:beginning offset:[tv.text rangeOfString:string].length];

    return ([tv textRangeFromPosition:beginning toPosition:end]);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is about a month late, but make sure you have the "selectable" property enabled in Interface Builder.

Credit: http://jon-nolen.blogspot.com/2013/10/uitextview-returns-nil-for-uitextinput.html

Comment: Yeah I found the solution but thanks for your answer.

Comment: Even after changing the selectable to YES, I am receiving nil from 'UITextInput' methods and properties. Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: Make sure you linked it correctly in your storyboards file? Confirm, via the debugger, that the UITextView object you're calling the methods on is not nil. Any luck?

Comment: I am not using storyboard, initializing it via code. TextView, TextContainers and layoutManager are not nil. But all the 'UITextInput' Methods and properties are returning nil. I still couldn't figure out the issue.

Comment: Have you set the text?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `UITextField` is added as a subview of another view. If it exists just in memory, the `beginningOfDocument` and `endOfDocument` properties will return `nil` for some reason.