# Property UITextField.beginningOfDocument is always nil on iOS 8, 9. Serious bug in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextinput

It seems that with iOS 8 and 9, Xcode 7 the properties [`beginningOfDocument`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInput/beginningOfDocument) and [`endOfDocument`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInput/endOfDocument) of [`UItextField`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html) are always `nil` whathever you do. Even worse they are not of an optional type (`UITextPosition?`) in Swift 2, instead they are of type `UITextPosition` - and still have `nil` value. Debuger calls it `<uninitialized>` instead of `nil` but it is the same thing as for its behaviour. To reproduce, put following code to any `UIViewController`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let textField = UITextField()
    textField.text = "Hello"
    view.addSubview(textField)
    let position: UITextPosition? = textField.beginningOfDocument //beginningOfDocument is of type UITextPosition, not optional
    //following line should always succeed
    let positionUnwrapped = position! //fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
}
```

Is this really a (huge) bug or am I missing something? Is there a workaround, perhaps some steps to fix the problem?

---

**EDIT:** Note that this problem is **not** answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20426048/311865). The suggested fixes there do not apply to my sample code:

1. My demonstration code does not use Interface Builder at all so [Gazzini's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21370083/311865) does not work. Besides, Interface Builder in XCode 7 does not have property `selectable` for `UITextView`, nor does the class itself declare such property.
2. My demonstration code adds `UITextField` to view hierarchy before `beginningOfDocument` is accessed so [m1h4's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31790486/311865) also isn't relevant.

Comment: I do not understand, if it is not an optional, why are you declaring it as an optional?Have you tried on iOS8?

Comment: @Andrea I declare it as an optional just to demonstrate the problem. If I did not not and just used the value (supposed to be `UITextPosition`) I would get unexpected behaviour (because it really is `nil`). On iOS 8 I get the same error, same behaviour.

Comment: Check here is already has been answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426048/uitextview-beginningofdocument-returns-nil

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's a bug in the Swift declaration of `beginningOfDocument`. You can report it to Apple [here](https://bugreport.apple.com/).

It will return a valid `UITextPosition` after it becomes first responder.

Comment: So calling `becomeFirstResponder` works nicelly for most apps. But mine is keyboard extension - and calling `becomeFirstResponder` inside results in this error:  `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Received more than one main-thread continuation for the current keyboard task.'` I could use `UITextView` instead which does not have this issue - but has another ([see my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33292099/311865)). Looks like there is not way out of this text input hell for me...

Comment: seems to be fixed in ios 11